# How to apply Leibniz's Rule to a Metal Pipe Temperature's Partial Derivative in this Example

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, integration

Refer to this image showing the temperature of a metal pipe at the inlet and the outlet:
[image: Temperature profile of a metal pipe]

The temperature $T(z,t)$ is a function of the length $z$ and time $t$. Let the average temperature be
$$T_\mathrm{avg}(t)=\frac{1}{2}\big(T(a,t)+T(b,t)\big).$$
Integrating the partial derivative of $T$ with respect to $t$, $\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}$ over the entire length of the pipe (from $z=a$ to $z=b$) and applying Leibniz's rule, we should get
$$\int_{z=a}^{z=b}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}T(z,t)dz=\frac{d}{dt}\int_{z=a}^{z=b}T(z,t)dz-T(b,t)\frac{db}{dt}+T(a,t)\frac{da}{at}.$$
In this [paper](https://www.modelica.org/events/Conference2002/papers/p31_Jensen.pdf) (eqs. (21) and (22)), the result is reported as follows:
$$\int_{z=a}^{z=b}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}T(z,t)dz=(b-a)\frac{d}{dt}T_\mathrm{avg}(t)+\big(T(a,t)-T_\mathrm{avg}(t)\big)\frac{da}{dt}+\big(T_\mathrm{avg}(t)-T(b,t)\big)\frac{db}{dt}.$$

Are the two equivalent? How to correctly solve this integral? Thanks!

**Note:** The integral in this question is only a portion of a larger integration problem in the energy balance, not reported for brevity. Equations (21) and (22) in the reference describe the complete energy balance.

Comment: You are aware that Eqns. 21 and 21 represent a heat balance on the wall of the pipe, not on the fluid, correct?

Comment: @ChetMiller You pointed out correctly. I updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry.  I was not able to make sense out of it either.  My assessment was the same as yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This answer is based on the original answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3813587/application-of-leibnizs-integral-rule/3814507#3814507)**. Some supplemental details relevant to the problem are added.

Referring to the original problem, let $T(z,t)$ vary linearly with $z$ as shown in the following figure:

[image: Temperature profile of a metal pipe]

As proposed in the original solution, integrating integral of the partial derivative of $T$ from $a$ to $b$ and applying Leibniz's Rule:
\begin{align}
\int_{a}^{b}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}T(z,t)dz&=\int_{a}^{b}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\big(T(z,t)-T_\mathrm{avg}(t)+T_\mathrm{avg}(t)\big)dz\\
&=\int_{a}^{b}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}T_\mathrm{avg}(t)dz + \underbrace{\int_{a}^{b}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\big(T(z,t)-T_\mathrm{avg}(t)\big)dz}_\text{apply Leibniz Rule}\\
&=(b-a)\frac{d}{dt}T_\mathrm{avg}(t)\\
&\quad+\underbrace{\frac{d}{dt}\int_{a}^{b}\big(T(z,t)-T_\mathrm{avg}(t)\big)dz+\big(T(a,t)-T_\mathrm{avg}(t)\big)\frac{da}{dt}+\big(T_\mathrm{avg}(t)-T(b,t)\big)\frac{db}{dt}.}_\text{Leibniz's Rule applied}
\end{align}

The area under the curve in the figure (shaded green) can be found using the integral $\int_{a}^{b}T(z,t)dz$. Approximating the curve with a straight line, we can write

\begin{align}
\int_{a}^{b}T(z,t)dz&\approx\underbrace{\frac{1}{2}(b-a)\big(T(b,t)-T(a,t)\big)}_\text{area of top triangle}+\underbrace{T(a,t)(b-a)}_\text{area of bottom rectangle}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\big(T(a,t)+T(b,t)\big)(b-a)=(b-a)T_\mathrm{avg}(t).
\end{align}

Thus, the second term in the third equality of the first equation vanishes, and the desired result is obtained:
$$\int_{a}^{b}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}T(z,t)dz\approx(b-a)\frac{d}{dt}T_\mathrm{avg}(t)+\big(T(a,t)-T_\mathrm{avg}(t)\big)\frac{da}{dt}+\big(T_\mathrm{avg}(t)-T(b,t)\big)\frac{db}{dt}.$$